# SharePoint 2016 onsite

Tags: calendar, 2016, resources

In SharePoint 2010, we had Group Work Lists and enabling these facilitated reservation options within the calendar.

I now use SharePoint 2016 On-Site and Group Work Lists are no longer available but I wish to use the resource function.

I wish to use a calendar on SharePoint 2016 to manage multiple meeting rooms, equipment etc.  users should be able to book them but the system should not allow them to double book.  I would also like the system to send a notification to specific users if a certain resource is requested, like Lunch or Refreshments.

how can I configure this in SharePoint 2016?

Comment: Adding to this question.  

I have come across many articles that show how to layer multiple calendars into one but it is not as slick as the original solution in SharePoint 2010.

I have also come across methods to edit the background XML file to show "Group Work Lists" however, the file path that is given doesn't seem to exist within my installation (it is a fresh install with no out of the box configuration applied)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much information out there on group work lists for SharePoint 2016, but people have been able to get it activated in 2013 even though it's been deprecated. **I did come across a forum question where someone was able to test and get it to work on SharePoint 2016 on premise.** The instructions are here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/70aad2cd-5c7e-4024-ba51-ef7fc0349b15/resource-management-sharepoint-2016?forum=appsforsharepoint

Hope that helps!